# Finding the residue of the improper integral $\frac{1}{z^4+4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^4+4}$$

the roots of this are:

$z^2=\pm i\sqrt{2} \implies z=\pm\sqrt{i\sqrt{2}}$ and $z=\pm i\sqrt{i\sqrt{2}}$

i.e. $$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z\pm\sqrt{i\sqrt{2}})(\pm i\sqrt{i\sqrt{2}})}$$

i would like to know if there is a better simplification for this pole, since the answer looks quiet tedious when i do it this way, i notice [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076597/the-sequence-of-improper-integrals-of-the-form-int-fracdx1x2n) that there is a special case for $\dfrac{1}{z^4+1}$, is there perhaps something similar for this -Thanks.

Comment: Not that it is necessary, but the change of variable $x=\sqrt{2}\,t$ transforms the problem into one of the problems linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of $z^4+4=0$ are $4^{1/4}e^{ik\pi/4}$ for odd $k$.  This turns out to be the four numbers $\pm1\pm i$

Comment: totally forgot about that, just to add  ![can use this to determine all the roots at k for order n][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bkRKi.png